# Enable Wireless adaptors on Dell 1018 inspiron

Tags: wireless, dell, inspiron

I have recently installed Ubuntu 10.04LTS -Lucid Lynx  on a dell Inspiron 1018 that came with windows 7 Starter.However my wifi is not working, I found the rfkill list command and on inputting I got the message dell wifi-soft blocked NO, Hardblocked Yes,notable is the fact that although I can see the bluetooth logo on the task bar  i can also see that bluetooth also says blocked

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Comment: please put the complete terminal output into your question: `rfkill list all` & `sudo lshw -class network`

Answer (score 3):

Had a similar problem with an Inspiron 1018, where wireless stopped working. What fixed it for me was to boot into Windows and re-enable wireless (F2 button) from there. Discovered later that it could be also re-enabled from the BIOS by doing a factory reset there, in case you've removed W7 altogether. Just making sure the BIOS claimed wireless was on was not enough.

Comment: Thank you Simon ,I checked and performed a factory reset and voila, it worked .Thank you

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem after installing ubuntu 11.10 on my hp touchsmart. anyway all you have to do is to connect you laptop to internet using ethernet cable, when connected to internet: go to system settings>additional drivers then select ur wireless adaptor and click activate, wait till it downloads and installs the driver software then restart ur machine and u're good to go. it worked for me i hope it works for u too.